# How can I use git commits signing in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

We are using gpg signing of commits in repository but when I try to commit changes in vscode I got this error:

```
gpg: cannot open tty `/dev/tty': No such device or address
error: gpg failed to sign the data
```

If I do "git commit" in vscode's terminal all is ok. So the problem not in git/gpg/gpg-agent I guess. Is there a way to make vscode deal with this?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

A [pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/27136) was recently merged and will be available in the next release of VS Code (August 2017 / 1.16). Alternatively, it is already available in insiders builds.

When available it can be enabled by adding the following to user or workspace settings (file > preferences > settings)

```
git.enableCommitSigning: true
```

Prerequisite: Having git setup to sign commits. Instructions can be found here -
 https://help.github.com/articles/signing-commits-using-gpg/

> To set all commits for a repository to be signed by default, in Git
>   versions 2.0.0 and above, run git config commit.gpgsign true. To set
>   all commits in any local repository on your computer to be signed by
>   default, run git config --global commit.gpgsign true.
>
> To store your GPG key passphrase so you don't have to enter it every
>   time you sign a commit, we recommend using the following tools:
>
> For Mac users, the GPG Suite allows you to store your GPG key
>   passphrase in the Mac OS Keychain. For Windows users, the Gpg4win
>   integrates with other Windows tools. You can also manually configure
>   gpg-agent to save your GPG key passphrase, but this doesn't integrate
>   with Mac OS Keychain like ssh-agent and requires more setup.

Comment: Do you know how to make it work on VS Code Version 1.28.1 with password-protected GPG keys?

Comment: what about configuring signoff commits? `git commit -s` ?